# How can I install Libre Office 5.0?

Tags: software-installation, libreoffice

On my Mac, my Ubuntu and my Phone I have Libre Office.

I know I can install from the repositories with `sudo apt-get install libreoffice` but that will install Libre Office 4 - and 5.0 has some great improvements.

How can I install Libre Office 5.0?

Comment: I am a little advanced ;P

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways.

### From the 5.0 PPA (recommended):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/libreoffice-5-0
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libreoffice
```

### From the `.deb` files (not recommended):

First, visit the Download page. To jump to the `.deb` version for [64 bit click here](https://www.libreoffice.org/download/libreoffice-fresh/?type=deb-x86&version=5.0.3&lang=en-GB), or for [32 bit click here](https://www.libreoffice.org/download/libreoffice-fresh/?type=deb-x86&version=5.0.3&lang=en-GB).

Next, click Download. Consider using the Torrent file as it reduces the load on their servers.

When the 229 MB download is finished (which will take 9.5 hours on dial up or 7 minutes on a High Speed T3 connection) you will need to extract the `.tar.gz` file.

Navigate to the file in your file manager, right click and chose "Extract Here".

Open a terminal and run this command:

```
cd ~/Downloads/LibreOffice5*/DEBS
```

Then, as the `README` says you need to run this command:

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

This will take a while, but when the command finishes, you will have Libre Office 5.0